# 'SignUp\login\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, node.js, module

I just started with React.js and I am stuch at this problem.I created a react app and when I executed 'npm start' this error 'SignUp\login\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
throw err;' showed up. plz help
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtgFP.png)

I tried uninstalling nodejs and npm still not working.                           .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should have shared how you started project. I assume you should executed `npm init` . It will download needed modules. Than you can start `npm start` or `npm dev`.